# R: graph multiple columns on one line

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

This seems simple, but I've tried multiple variations of `matplot`, `ggplot2`, regular old `plot`...I can't get any to do what I need.

I have a gigantic dataframe of years, months, and observations. I simplified it down to number of observations per month, per year, see below. I'm not sure why it read in with the "X" in front of each column heading, but if it's not going to affect the code, right now I don't care.

```
head(storms)

X Month X1992 X1993 X1994 
1 1     1     2     1    
2 2     2     4     1    
3 3     3    26    10   
4 4     4    47    26 
5 5     5   969   615
```

The full (simplified) set is 10 columns of years (1992-2001), each with 12 months/rows of totals (1 storm in Jan 1992, 26 storms in March 1993...). I need simply to plot these all on an x-axis 120 months long, # of observations per month on the y-axis. It could be a line or bars or vertical lines. I've seen many ways to plot 20 lines with 12 months on the x-axis; that is *not* what I'm going for. I also need to label the years every 12 months, but I think I can figure that out after I get this block out of the way.

In other words (I hope this is more clear if the previous is not):

- y axis: # of storms, `ylim=c(0-1000)`
- x axis: 10 sets of months (Jan-Dec, 1992-2001, 120 months total). The only labels will be the years, every 12 months of course.

I know I'm just thinking about it wrong, could someone please set my head straight?

(first post; please also tell me if I'm not formatting or inquiring properly!)

Comment: Last night, `idvar="Month"` threw errors (sorry I can't reproduce them); `idvar=storms$Month` passed with no errors. I think they are doing the same thing? This morning, after one round of errors with `idvar="Month"`, I made that chunk all one line (worked), then broke it up again & `idvar="Month"` worked, except it didn't remove the "X"s in front of the column headings. I get the same graph, though. Maybe someone else has this issue: try, try again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]is this something you are looking for? If I am not mistaken, you may want to rearrange your data frame. You wanna make your data frame longer rather than wider. Then, you can draw a figure. The thing is that you have 120 month. So you may need to think plot space issue. But at least this example let you move forward. I hope this helps you.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample data
month <- rep(c(1:12), each = 1, times = 2)
nintytwo <-  runif(24, 0, 20)
nintythree <-  runif(24, 0, 20)

# Crate a data frame
ana <- data.frame(month, nintytwo, nintythree)

# Make the data longer rather than wider.
bob <- gather(ana, year, value, -month)
bob$month <- as.factor(bob$month)

# Draw a firure
cathy <- ggplot(bob, aes(x= year,y = value, fill = month)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
cathy
```

Comment: Both work great, but this one is shorter & gives slightly more of the look I was hoping for (though my advisor is going to be angry about the colors). I didn't say originally that bars would be better than lines, for my data it just gives a little more information than the line.

Comment: If you want to choose your own colours, you can use `scale_fill_manual()`. For example, you can do something like this. `scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "yellow", "green","black", "red", "blue","orange", "pink", "black","blue", "yellow", "black"))`

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this. Thanks!  
If anyone else has this question, here's super specific:  
`cathy + scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","black","black","black",  "black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black"))`  
I'm sure there's an easier way, but it's 5am & this code works. Rock over London, roll on, Chicago.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using base R :

```
# create an example data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Month=1:12)
for(y in 1992:2001){
  tmp <- data.frame(X=as.integer(abs(rnorm(12,mean=2,sd=10))))
  colnames(tmp) <- paste("X",y,sep="")
  df <- cbind(df,tmp)
}

# reshape to long format (one column with n.of storms, and period columns)
long <- reshape(df[,-1], idvar="Month", ids=df$Month, 
        times=names(df[,-1]), timevar="Year",
        varying = list(names(df[,-1])), 
        direction = "long",v.names="Storms")

# remove the "X" from the year
long$Year <- substr(long$Year,2,nchar(long$Year))

nYears <- length(unique(long$Year))

# plot the line
plot(x=1:nrow(long),y=long$Storms,type="l",
     xaxt="n",main="Monthly Storms",
     xlab="Period",ylab="Storms",col="RoyalBlue")

# add custom labels
axis(1,at=((1:nYears)*12)-6,labels=unique(long$Year))

# add vertical lines
abline(v=c(0.5,((1:nYears)*12)+0.5),col="Gray80",lty=2)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It says I'm not supposed to do this, but...Yes! Finally, I am unstuck. I wish I'd asked last week. Thank you, thank you!